# Android OpenCV color detection in HSV space

Tags: android, opencv, colors, detection

i tried to wrote color(green) detection code for android(live camera view) in OpenCV. first use RGB space and it's half okay but when switch to the HSV space the result is the mess !!!

this is my code

```
    Mat A = src;
    Mat B = dst;
    Imgproc.cvtColor(A, A, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV,3);
    Size sizeA = A.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA.height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeA.width; j++) {
            double[] data = A.get(i, j);
            if (data[0]>=95 && data[0]<=130 & data[1]>=150 && data[1]<=255 & data[2]<=150 && data[2]<=255){
                 data[0] = 120;
                 data[1] = 255 ;
                 data[2] = 255 ;
            }
            else
                  data[0] = 100;
                  data[1] = 255;
                  data[2] = 255;
              B.put(i, j, data);
        }
    Imgproc.cvtColor(B, B, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA, 4);}
}
```

what's wrong with this code ? and this method run slowly.why?

(i new to android and OpenCV)

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You should probably convert from BGR (not RGB) to HSV, but that depends on your code before this snippet

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(A, A, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV,3);
```

Check your if statement and use always `&&` (you sometimes use `&`)

You should convert from HSV to RGB and then to RGBA

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(B, B, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB, 3);}
Imgproc.cvtColor(B, B, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA, 4);}
```

Comment: Tnx,the && for value between two other value like b : a<b<c and & for separate them. no i think it's right ! and about HSV to RGB then to RGBA i do that but every think turn to bullish ! why ? (before it, every other color turn to dark purple and green show as green)

Comment: You' re putting double into unsigned char

Comment: If it's double, use value in [0,1], not in [0,255]

Comment: ok,tnx. but i normalize the value everything is black when i use it. (the value is right)